# Hibernate Envers not working with JTA Transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers, weblogic12c

I am getting the following error when a hibernate domain object is saved.

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unable to
>   create revision because of non-active transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: Unable to create
>   revision because of non-active transaction

If I disable envers, everything works ok and the object is saved successfully.

```
<prop key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">false</prop>
```

My Setup is as follows

I have included the following in my `sessionFactory` bean

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
...
      <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
...
```

I am looking up the weblogic datasource using the follwing configuration

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc.myDsXA" /> 
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just had the same issue myself.  I notice there are no answers but I wonder if you found anything offline?

Comment: No, still can't get it working

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the "jtaTransactionManager" attribute to LocalSessionFactoryBean.
Properties hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class and hibernate.transaction.factory_class are no longer required in Hibernate 4.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
...
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
...
</bean>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

Comment: Actually I already had that but I didn't post it `<property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the property `hibernate.transaction.factory_class`

from

```
org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
```

to

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
```

solved the problem for me.

See here: http://koenserneels.blogspot.de/2012/05/migrating-from-hibernate-3-to-4-with.html

and here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9480

Answer (score 0):

**I set the order for the transaction advisor**

http://mejagged.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/orghibernateenversexceptionauditexcepti.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the way I got the session

from

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public T save(T t) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

to

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public T save(T t) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It Doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong perse. I am currently running into a similar issue using Grails and it from my searching it looks like its an issue with Hibernate ORM: [HHH-8524](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8524). The workaround as specified in the link is to explicitly begin the Hibernate Transaction.